# Dimensionless units like Percent are not treated consistently by functions like Exp or Log. How can pitfalls be avoided?

Tags: units

There are so many false calculations out there that working with `Quantity` und units—at least initially—should be mandatory in many applications.

Alas, implementation in the Wolfram Language sometimes seems to be in the way. I will give a simple calculation of compound interest as example:

```
r =  Quantity[ 5, "Percent"/"Years" ]; (* a continuously compounding rate *)

t = Quantity[ 10, "Years" ]; (* time for interest to accrue *)

initialCapital = Quantity[ 1000, "USDollars" ]; 

initialCapital Exp[ r t ]
```

[image: Result]

While in this special case using [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html?q=Normal) and `N` come to the rescue, it seems that the treatment of units that are compatible to `"DimensionlessUnit"`  like `Percent` is not consistent accross WL functions.

Note the following:

```
Log[ 1. + 5 Quantity["Percent"] ]
(* 0.0487902 *)

Log[ 1. + Quantity[ 5, "Percent"] ]
(* 0.0487902 *)

Exp[ 5. Quantity["Percent"] ]
(* E^Quantity[5., "Percent"] *)
```

Is there some principle here? How to best work with units in these cases?

---

A support case with the identification **[CASE:4935014]** was created. Please include this ID in any future correspondence with Wolfram Technical Support regarding this issue.

Comment: `Log` and `Exp` do seem to have different opinions on whether "Percent" quantities should go through `Normal` or not. Until `Exp` figures it out you might be better off always normalizing it yourself: `r = Normal[Quantity[5, "Percent"]]/Quantity["Years"]`

Comment: `1. + 5 Quantity["Percent"]` evaluates to a pure number, `1.05`.  So `Exp[1. + 5 Quantity["Percent"]]` evaluates to a pure number. `Log` and `Exp` aren't really involved with that example, since the `Quantity[]` goes away. For the last example, `Log[Quantity[5, "Percent"]]` also does not evaluate. I thought *`Exp` and `Log` took dimensionless arguments,* although percent could be argued to be dimensionless. Perhaps `Quantity[]` objects are treated as having dimensions, but `0. + Quantity[5, "Percent"]` suggests special cases exist.

Comment: More workarounds: (1) Avoid `"Percent"`; use `1/100`; (2) `initialCapital Exp[1 + r t]/E`; (3) `initialCapital Exp[0. + r t]`; (4) `initialCapital Exp[r t/Quantity[100, "Percent"]]`

Comment: Interestingly, most (transcendental) functions do not treat `"Percent"` as a pure number, including `Power`. Some exceptions are the trig. functions except `Sec` and `InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], r t]`. There may be others but I stopped looking. It's odd that five of the six trig. funs. handle `"Percent"`. -- As for aiding humanity: (1b) Strip `"Percent"` from input and internally avoid percent; put it back in output when appropriate...(5) Report to WRI and wait for them to fix it (probably the slowest workaround, but also the best solution assuming no other).

Comment: Just to clarify, I agree with you. It may be hard to decide when to propagate `"Percent"` as a unit and when to convert to a number, but `Exp[r t]` is an obvious, common case. But given that it doesn't work, I assumed you would report it but not wait for a workaround. Here's another approach to get rid of just `"Percent"`, whether or not `x` has any units: `UnitConvert[x, Information[x, "Unit"] /. "Percent" | _Information -> 1]`. -- It's odd that Mma has `º` for `Degree` but not `%` for percent conversion, but interest in financial math didn't start until around V8 (and `PercentForm` is V12).

Comment: I think it does NOT make sense to `Exp` or `Log`   a quantity with units. There may be an equivalence between a percentage and a pure number, but the moment you state `Quantity[5,"Percent"] ` you are stating a unit not a number. I don't think it's reasonable to expect Mathematica to deal with the concept behind the units, or attempts to enforce *normal use* or *physics*. I think that what the OP is asking is not something that would be desirable for Mathematica to provide.

Comment: @rhermans I tend to agree

Comment: @rhermans I beg to differ: The unit associated with `Quantity[ 5, "Percent" ]` is `"DimensionlessUnit"` and there is a reason that it can also be represented by `1`. All we should ask the WL to do is to _consistently_ treat such quantities. Your appraoch is fair, but it is not the way WL treats all of these cases, which is clearly confusing.

Comment: @gwr so you want Mathematica to automatically strip the units of any quantity `CompatibleUnitQ["DimensionlessUnits"]` when applying some functions like `Exp` , `Power` and `Log` but not others like `Times` and `Plus`. I say that I don't like these exceptions and that such a task should be on the user.

Comment: @rhermans As you may see from my community wiki solution, I indeed feel that the user should decide, which is possible using `Off["Quantities"]` and `On["Quantities"]`. Since Percent, BasisPoints to me is nothing different than a unit multiplier like kilo-, I could well live with it being automatically stripped. But as you say, it should be easy for the user to decide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the approaches in the comments (thanks a lot!) solve the issue, the question triggered me to try to *"have my cake and eat it as well"*, i.e., enter quantities but decide globally whether they are used and what will happen if I just want magnitudes—after all using `Quantity` slows down things.

### A Litte Package For Conditional Quantities

The use of quantities with appropriate units should be mandatory for any *mathematical model* of reality, so that we may have a chance to validate equations.

While using `Quantity` is the way to go, there is a price to pay with regard to performance—likely a reason that using `Quantity` may be avoided and mere comments are used for units, which have the downside, that we can't let Mathematica help us.

So a nice thing to have may actually be to allow the *verbose* use of `Quantity` so that users can enter `10 Quantity["Percent"]` instead of `0.1` (don't laugh, it happens). But at the same time, we may use `ConditionalQuantity` as a wrapper to guide *conversion* with regard to the use in our models.

The following package thus has two main functions:

1. Allow to use `On["Quantities"]` and `Off["Quantities"]` to switch between `UnitConvert` and `QuantityMagnitude` for quanties as appropriate.
2. Tell Mathematica how we would like to have our verbose units be interpreted either for `UnitConvert` or `QuantityMagnitude`.

We can achieve (2) by using:

- `ConditionalQuantity[quantity]` to use `QuantityMagnitude` as is or to keep quantity as is, i.e., no target units are provided.
- `ConditionalQuantity[quantity, "Canonical" ]` to try to go for the canonical unit, if it exists.
- `ConditionalQuantity[quantity, "Normal" ]` to get rid of all units that are compatible to `"DimensionlessUnit"` (i.e., replace those units by `1`), but leave the other units unchanged.
- `ConditionalQuantity[quantity, unit]` to tell `QuantityMagnitude` and `UnitConvert` that `unit` is the target unit. (Instead of `unit` we also provide a reference `Quantity`.)

#### Code

```
BeginPackage[ "ConditionalQuantities`" ]

Quantity::inuse = "Quantities in use."

QuantitiesOffQ::usage = "\
QuantitiesOffQ[] returns True, if messages related to Quantities have been switched off using Off[\"Quantities\"].\
The function will by default be used by ConditionalQuantity to decide whether a magnitude or a quantity is to be returned."

$numericalUnitRules = "\
$numericalUnitRules is a list of replacement rules for numerical units like Percent, BasisPoints, Thousand etc."

ConditionalQuantity::usage = "\
ConditionalQuantity[quantity] will return QuantityMagnitude[quantity] if QuantitiesOffQ[] is True and quantity, if this is not the case.\n\
ConditionalQuantity[quantity, \"Canonical\" ] will call ConditionalQuantity[quantity, unit], where unit is the canonical unit.\n\
ConditionalQuantity[quantity, \"Normal\" ] will call ConditionalQuantity[quantity, unit], where unit is QuantityUnit[quantity] where all parts\
 compatible to \"DimensionlessUnit\" have been replaced by 1.\n\
ConditionalQuantity[quantity, refQuantity] will call ConditionalQuantity[quantity, QuantityUnit[refQuantity]].\n\
ConditionalQuantity[quantity, unit] will return QuantityMagnitude[quantity,unit] or UnitConversion[quantity, unit] depending on QuantitiesOffQ[].\
 If units is are not compatible, unit input is disregarded and ConditionalQuantity[quantity] is called."

Begin["`Private`"]

$numericalUnitRules = Map[
    Rule[ #, 1 ]&,
        {
            "Percent",
            "BasisPoints",
            "Dozen",
            "Hundred",
            "Thousand",
            "HundredThousand",
            "Million",
            "Billion",
            "Trillion"
        }
]

$MessageGroups = Join[ $MessageGroups, { "Quantities" :> { Quantity::inuse } } ]

QuantitiesOffQ[] := HoldPattern[ Quantity::inuse ] /. Messages[ Quantity ] // Not @* FreeQ[ $Off ]

ConditionalQuantity[ q_Quantity ] := If[ QuantitiesOffQ[], QuantityMagnitude @ q, q ]

ConditionalQuantity[ q_Quantity, refq_Quantity ] := ConditionalQuantity[ q, QuantityUnit @ refq ]

ConditionalQuantity[ q_Quantity, "Canonical" ] := Enclose[
    With[
        {
            canonicalUnit = ConfirmQuiet[
                QuantityVariableCanonicalUnit @ QuantityVariable @ UnitDimensions @ q
            ]
        }
        ,
        ConditionalQuantity[ q, canonicalUnit ]
    ]
]

ConditionalQuantity[ q_Quantity, "Normal" ] := With[
    {
        normalUnit = QuantityUnit[ q ] /. $numericalUnitRules
    }
    , 
    If[ normalUnit === 1, 
        (* then *) ConditionalQuantity[ q, "DimensionlessUnit" ],
        (* else *) ConditionalQuantity[ q, normalUnit ] 
    ]
]

ConditionalQuantity[ q_Quantity, unit_ ] /; CompatibleUnitQ[ q, unit ] unit := If[ QuantitiesOffQ[],
    (* then *)
    QuantityMagnitude[ q, unit ],
    (* else *)
    UnitConvert[ q, unit ]
]

ConditionalQuantity[ q_Quantity, unit_ ] /; Not @ CompatibleUnitQ[ q, unit ] := ConditionalQuantity[q]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

### Examples

Assuming that we loaded the package with `` <<ConditionalQuantities` ``  or `Needs`, we can now do the following:

```
On["Quantities"] (* Not really necessary since it is default *)

r := ConditionalQuantity[ Quantity[5., "Percent"/"Years"], "Normal" ];
t := ConditionalQuantity[ Quantity[10, "Years"] ]; 
initialCapital := ConditionalQuantity[ Quantity[1000, "USDollars"] ];

initialCapital Exp[r t]
(* $1648.72 *)

r
(* 0.05 per year *)

Do[ initialCapital Exp[r t], 1000] // RepeatedTiming
{0.957131, Null}

Off["Quantities"]

initialCapital Exp[ r t ]
(* 1648.72 *)

r
(* 0.05 *)

Do[ initialCapital Exp[r t], 1000] // RepeatedTiming
{0.413421, Null}
```

Comment: This solution is probably overdone for simple use cases, but it may help to propagate the (important) use of `Quantity` to verify calculations and avoid errors in magnitude. Using `QuantityMagnitude` unfortunately is risky with `Percent` and the like. I'll make this a community answer in the hope that it'll be useful and improved upon.

Comment: Just updated the code as it is not `KnownUnitQ` that will matter, but rather `CompatibleUnitQ`. Also using `Enclose` to make sure there is no `Failure[...]` regarding the search for a canonical unit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`UnitDimensions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitDimensions.html) and [`UnitConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert.html) to unwrap dimensionless quantities.

With `r`, `t`, and `initialCapital` in OP and

```
dimensionlessQuantityQ[q_Quantity] := UnitDimensions[q] === {}
```

then

```
N[initialCapital Exp[r t]] /. q_Quantity?dimensionlessQuantityQ :> UnitConvert[q]
```

> ```
> Quantity[1648.7212707001281`, "USDollars"]
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This works for expressions with pure dimensionless units, but it will not get rid of embedded dimensionless units: `N[Quantity[5., "Percent"/ "Year" ] ] /. 
 q_Quantity?dimensionlessQuantityQ :> UnitConvert[q]` will give `5.% per year`. I should have made clearer, that I would like to have more control about magnitudes.

Comment: @gwr Yes. that is a bit of a predicament because `"Percent"` is implicitly carrying a divide by 100 operation with it and it makes me wonder if any other dimensionless units are doing something similar.  And a quick check with dimensionless unit `"Million"` says they are.

Comment: One might want to consider the difference between `UnitDimensions[q] == {}`
and `UnitDimensions[q] === {}` in bad input like
`dimensionlessQuantityQ[Quantity[1, "foo"]]`. It makes no substantial difference in the example, but it does in situations in which a non `True`/`False` result has an effect, as in `If[dimensionlessQuantityQ[...],...]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 @Edmund Why not use `CompatibleUnitQ[ q, 1 ]`?

Comment: @gwr Because I know little about `Quantity` stuff. When you raised the issue of the rest of humanity, my first thought was why in the world would the rest of humanity ever want to deal with `Quantity`. :)  But I work in a dimensionless field, and my view is probably from a parochial bias. BTW, `CompatibleUnitQ` seems to compare `UnitDimensions[q] === UnitDimensions[Quantity[1, "PureUnities"]]`.  Didn't know `"PureUnities"` before. Since `Quantity[1, "PureUnities"]` converts to `1`, which we started with, there seems to be some wasted CPU cycles in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it's better to be explicit in telling Mathematica when you want percents to be treated as units or as numbers. In the original post, the problem was setup with percent as a unit. At some point, the desire was to convert to a representation where the percent was a number. Rather than expect Mathematica to correctly infer when such conversions are desired, why not just be explicit? Any of the following, or any similar "forcing" to a new representation, seem appropriate to me:

```
initialCapital Exp[r t] /. q_Quantity :> Normal[q]
initialCapital Exp[r t] /. q : Quantity[_, "Percent"] :> Normal[q]
initialCapital Exp[r t] /. q_Quantity :> UnitConvert[q]
initialCapital Exp[r t] /. q : Quantity[_, "Percent"] :> UnitConvert[q]
```

Comment: You can apply `Normal` or `UnitConvert` directly, so replacement is not needed. Also note that there are "BasisPoint", "Dozen", "Thousand" etc. as well. When the result is not a numerical unit like "Percent"/ "Year" `Normal` will not help and `UnitConvert` will go for a canonical unit which converts years to seconds. Compare to the solution I posted, which does not have these downsides.

Comment: The point is to be explicit. Your assertions are not 100% correct based on my experiments, but I won't argue the details.